# ASP MVC3 - Using partial view to append new HTML elements to page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I am currently using an Ajax call on my ASP MVC3 view to append a new list item to the page. The view makes the Ajax call, which calls a controller `ViewResult` action, which returns the partial view. The Ajax is then set to call the `.append(html)` method on the `<div>` element the call originated from.

The problem is that instead of appending the new row, the entire view goes away and only the partial is displayed.

Here is the code in the view. This view uses a view model with a list object of a separate model. This portion of the code calls the partial view to display each of the items in the list object.

```
@model Monet.ViewModel.BankListViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Stat(s) Fixed</legend>
        <table>
        <th>State Code</th>
        <th>Agent ID</th>
        <th></th>
            <div class="fixedRows">
                @foreach(var item in Model.Fixed)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.AgentId))
                    {

                            @Html.Partial("FixedPartialView", item) 

                    }      
                }
            </div>
        </table>
        <br />
        @Html.ActionLink("Add another", "BlankFixedRow", null, new { id = "addFixed"})
    </fieldset>
}
```

Here is the `addFixed` Ajax call

```
$("#addFixed").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) { $("#fixedRows").append(html); }
    });
    return false;
});
```

and this is the `ViewResult` controller action that the Ajax calls

```
    public ViewResult BlankFixedRow()
    {
        SelectList tmpList = new SelectList(new[] { "AL", "AK", "AS", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FM", "FL", "GA", "GU", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MH", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NA", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "MP", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PW", "PA", "PR", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "US", "VT", "VI", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY" });
        ViewBag.StateCodeList = tmpList;

        return View("FixedPartialView", new BankListAgentId());
    }
```

Finally, this is the partial view.

```
@model Monet.Models.BankListAgentId


@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Fixed"))
{
    <tr id="item-@Model.AgentId">
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateCode,
                (SelectList)ViewBag.StateCodeList, Model.StateCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AgentId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgentId)
        </td>
        <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="$('#item-@Model.AgentId').parent().remove();" style="float:right;">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
}
```

When the `Add another` link is selected the page goes from looking like this

[image]

to this

[image]

Per comments below here is the HTML for the page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Fixed.index" autocomplete="off" value="6dd1b028-14f7-4400-95d1-a803c2521b68" />
        <tr id="item-">
            <td>
                <select id="Fixed_6dd1b028-14f7-4400-95d1-a803c2521b68__StateCode" name="Fixed[6dd1b028-14f7-4400-95d1-a803c2521b68].StateCode"><option>AL</option>
<option>AK</option>
<option>AS</option>
<option>AZ</option>

.
.
. <-removed list of all 50 states for clarity
</select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="text-box single-line" id="Fixed_6dd1b028-14f7-4400-95d1-a803c2521b68__AgentId" name="Fixed[6dd1b028-14f7-4400-95d1-a803c2521b68].AgentId" type="text" value="" />

            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
            </td>

        </tr>
                    </section>
```

EDIT

After reading the comments below I changed the table tag to `<table id="fixedRows">`, however, this returned the same result. I then changed the `success` attribute of the Ajax call to include some basic HTML like so

```
success: function (html) { $("#fixedRows").append("<tr><td>New</td></tr>"); }
```

but again, got the same result. After setting a breakpoint both in Visual Studio and Chrome's debugger, I was able to see that the Ajax is never being called. Instead the call to the controller action is made, and the partial view is loaded on it's own, instead of being appended to `<table id="fixedRows">`.

Still working of getting around this, however, if anyone has any ideas. Thx!

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use Ajax to do the partial call? When you use Ajax you have to remember the state of the previous page in order for Ajax to redisplay the page

Comment: I'm following this blog post: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Comment: Can you inspect the rendered markup of the table after clicking 'Add another' and post that?

Comment: probably doesn't solve your problem but `<div class="fixedRows">` doesn't match your selector `$("#fixedRows").append(html)`

Comment: Probably yes, the link click works well and you are redirect to the page of the view (instead of importing the html via ajax).

Comment: I don't think you want to use AJAX to do this.

Comment: Good Question you helped me a lot thanks NealR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the reason this was happening wound up being pretty simple. Due to the ActionLink that was being used, the controller action would fire before the jQuery. This was causing the partial view to wipe out the entire `Edit` view. By binding the jQuery to a hyperlink within a `$(document).ready` block, the jQuery functioned like normal. Below is the tag and the updated jQuery

```
<a href="#" class="addFixed">Add Another</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".addFixed").click(function () {
        //alert('test');
        event.preventDefault();        
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("BlankFixedRow", "BankListMaster")',
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) { $("#fixedRows").append(html); }
        });
    });

    $("#addVariable").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("BlankFixedRow", "BankListMaster")',
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) { $("#variableRows").append(html); }
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way this could occur with the code you have is if it's not *replacing* the page content with that simple bit of HTML, but rather *directly loading* that action in the browser tab. Which your action link will do by default.

1. Make sure that your click handler for that "Add another" link employs `event.preventDefault()` or simply returns false; If you don't prevent the default action of the link, you AJAX code will do it's thing, and then the browser will load the link like normal, making it look like it didn't work.
2. Make sure there's no JavaScript errors on the page. If the JS stops working, then the default behavior, again, will take over and you get the result you see.

Comment: Regarding item 1: the current jQuery does have `return false;` specified at the end of the handler. Regarding item 2: This is the only jQuery/Javascript/Ajax code on the page. Just to make sure, however, I ran it step by step using Chrome's debugger and saw no errors.

Comment: I also tried replacing the success attribute with some basic html like so: `success: function (html) { $("#fixedRows").append("<tr><td>New</td></tr>");`, but I received the same results (partial view replacing the previous page). Could I be using the `@Html.ActionLink` incorrectly?

Comment: I don't know you jquery version but "success" is deprecated in 1.8, use ".done(function(html){})".  Put a chrome debugger breakpoint in this function...

Comment: Just did that and found out the Ajax isn't even getting called.

Comment: It's not an issue of using `@Html.ActionLink` incorrectly. It's just a link. The fact that you received the same results even after explicitly appending different HTML confirms that it's still just loading the link, though, and not handling it via AJAX. Try using `event.preventDefault()` which is a little more explicit than relying on a return value of false.

Comment: Still no luck.. Put what I had in this fiddle in case you want to take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/68Lud/1/

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` needs to be the first line of your handler. I can't test anything with that fiddle since it incorporates Razor markup, but my guess is that the browser is proceeding with loading the link while the AJAX method is still trying to set itself up because the default action is not prevented before that point.

Comment: My fault, i had changed that line of code to go first in the `.click` function, but wound up getting the same result. Are you sure it's not something with the ActionLink? Ajax seems to be getting completely passed up no matter what changes I make to it.

Comment: Hmm... well I was thinking the link obviously works, so @Html.ActionLink call must be fine, but I didn't stop to consider that you're also setting the id attribute that you'll be referencing in your JS. I think actually that you're a parameter off, so it should be: `@Html.ActionLink("Add another", "BlankFixedRow", null, null, new { id = "addFixed"})` (a second null parameter is needed). The parameters provided aren't specific enough bring in the overload that includes `htmlAttributes` so your anonymous object is actually going into the route values parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your usage of divs inside your `<table>` tags is confusing `jQuery.append`.

Try the following instead:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Stat(s) Fixed</legend>
    <table id="fixedRows">
        <tr>
            <th>State Code</th>
            <th>Agent ID</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach(var item in Model.Fixed)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.AgentId))
            {
                @Html.Partial("FixedPartialView", item) 
            }      
        }
    </table>
    <br />
    @Html.ActionLink("Add another", "BlankFixedRow", null, new { id = "addFixed"})
</fieldset>
```

Note, also, that I have used `id="fixedRows"` instead of `class="fixedRows"` as this is what you're specifying in your jQuery.

Compare:

- Broken: http://jsfiddle.net/83EAT/1/
- Working: http://jsfiddle.net/hT34k/3/

Comment: Interesting.. I changed the code in my view to look exactly like yours in the answer. I got the same results, so I tried copying your `success` attribute like so: `success: function (html) { $("#fixedRows").append("<tr><td>New</td></tr>");`, thinking I would at least be able to see a new `<tr>` element added to the page. Instead, I got the exact same results as before - the entire view gone and replaced with just the partial.

Answer (score 0):

I try an avoid doing AJAX calls on partial views. AJAX requires you remember the state of the last page in order to redisplay the information. That being said you can go back to the controller and call the partial view and just have the server call display the partial in tandem with your view:

```
 @Html.Partial("FixedPartialView", new BankListAgentId(){/*Construct the View Model Here here. assign the properties to your view model */  AgentId = /*however your creating this*/})
```

I do not think AJAX is the way to go with this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by `construct the object here`? Currently the new HTML from the partial is sent via the controller and appended to the table.

Comment: Edited my post for more clarity.